# Extract Specific Filetypes From Multiple Zips to one Folder in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, zip, 7zip

I have Several zip files that Contain multiple filetypes. The ONLY ones I am interested in are the .txt files. I need to extract the .txt files only and place them in a folder of their own, ignoring all other file types in the zips files.

All the zip files are in the same folder.

Example

```
-foo.zip

--1.aaa
--2.bbb
--3.ccc
--4.txt

-foo2.zip

--5.aaa
--6.bbb
--7.ccc
--8.txt
```

I want to have `4.txt` and `8.txt` extracted to another folder. I can't for the life of my figure it out and spent ages looking,  googling and trying. Even managing to delete to zips once in a while :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) type to programmatically inspect the archive before extracting:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression

$destination = "C:\destination\folder"

# Locate zip file
$zipFile = Get-Item C:\path\to\file.zip

# Open a read-only file stream
$zipFileStream = $zipFile.OpenRead()

# Instantiate ZipArchive
$zipArchive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive]::new($zipFileStream)

# Iterate over all entries and pick the ones you like
foreach($entry in $zipArchive.Entries){
    if($entry.Name -like '*.txt'){
        # Create new file on disk, open writable stream
        $targetFileStream = $(
            New-Item -Path $destination -Name $entry.Name -ItemType File
        ).OpenWrite()

        # Open stream to compressed file, copy to new file stream
        $entryStream = $entry.Open()
        $entryStream.BaseStream.CopyTo($targetFileStream)

        # Clean up
        $targetFileStream,$entryStream |ForEach-Object Dispose
    }
}

# Clean up
$zipArchive,$zipFileStream |ForEach-Object Dispose
```

Repeat for each zip file.

Note that the code above has *very minimal error-handling*, and is to be read as *an example*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set-Location "Extraction path"
@("full path of foo.zip","full path of foo2.zip") | ForEach {
  & "Full path of 7z.exe" x '-i!*.txt' $_.FullName
}
```

- Sets location to the path where files will be extracted.
- Passes a array of zip files to for loop.
- Exexute 7z command to extract only zip files.

Comment: Close but no cigar. - I do have 7z installed though.

& : The term '7z.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:5
+   & "7z.exe" x '-i!*.txt' $_.FullName
+     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (7z.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I am also wanting ALL the zips in that folder to be done in one go. I would rather not specify the filenames of the zips as there are hundreds.

Comment: Please provide the full path of 7z.exe (See edited code)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

1. Go through each `.zip` file in a folder.
2. Extract archive into separate folder.
3. Extract `.txt` file from folder.
4. Copy files into destination folder containing all `.txt` files. This will overwrite files if they already exist in the destination folder.
5. Cleanup extracted folders once finished.

**Demo:**

```
function Copy-ZipArchiveFiles {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({
            if (-not(Test-Path $_ -PathType Container))
            {
                throw "The source path $_ does not exist. Please enter a valid source path."
            }
            else
            {
                $true
            }
        })]
        [string]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim()))
            {
                throw "The Destination path is null or empty. Please enter a valid destination path."
            } 
            else 
            {
                $true
            }
        })]
        [string]$Destination,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [string[]]$Include
    )

    # Create destination folder if it doesn't already exist
    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $Destination -PathType Container))
    {
        try 
        {
            New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch
        {
            throw "The destination path $Destination is invalid. Please enter a valid destination path."
        }
    }

    # Go through each .zip file
    foreach ($zipFile in Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.zip)
    {

        # Get folder name from zip file w/o .zip at the end
        $zipFolder = Split-Path $zipFile -LeafBase

        # Get full folder path
        $folderPath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $zipFolder

        # Expand .zip file into folder if it doesn't exist
        if (-not(Test-Path -Path $folderPath -PathType Container)) 
        {
            Expand-Archive -Path $zipFile.FullName -DestinationPath $folderPath
        }

        # Copy files into destination folder
        foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Include $Include -Recurse)
        {
            Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $Destination
        }

        # Delete extracted folders
        Remove-Item -Path $folderPath -Recurse -Force
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Copy-ZipArchiveFiles `
    -Path "C:\path\to\zip\files" `
    -Destination "C:\path\to\text\files" `
    -Include "*.txt"
```

**Note:** Could also use this for multiple extension types as well by passing `-Include *.txt, *.pdf`. I also went a bit overboard in the parameter error checking, but I believe in writing robust code. Good habit to get into when writing your own cmdlets anyways :)