# PowerShell extract the content of subfolder (all files and folders) of zip archive

Tags: powershell

I have a zipped folder named install and I need to extract a content of that folder (all files and folders) to some other destination using power shell. I tried to do the following:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath C:\temp\install.zip -DestinationPath C:\"Program Files"\mbeats
```

In this case I extract install folder itself into mbeats folder, not the content of install folder.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks, Dragan

Comment: Hey, I noticed this is a duplicate of [this question I already closed as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365057/powershell-extract-the-content-of-subfolder-of-zip-archive) - were you unable to solve the problem using the answers?

Comment: No I was not able to resolve it with suggested post. I need to extract all files and folders from zip archive not specific type of files such as .txt or so.

Comment: Well, that's simply a question of changing the `if($entry.Name -like "*.txt")` statement to whatever suits your need, ie `if($entry.FullName -like '*install*')`

Comment: I tried to change if($entry.Name -like "*.txt") to if($entry.FullName -like '*') and else but in that cases it extracts everything and doesn't keep directory structure. I am trying to extract zip archive which contains one folder and then there is a directory structure in that folder which I need to keep.

Answer (score 0):

If your zip file - called "install.zip" - contains a folder - called "install" - that contains the folders and files you are interested in, then your observation is indeed the intended behaviour. Keep in mind that you do not have to put all files into a folder ("install") before archiving them into a zip file ("install.zip").

If you do not want to extract your whole zip archive, but all files and folders inside the folder "install", then you have to access those items piece by piece, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60871547/extract-specific-filetypes-from-multiple-zips-to-one-folder-in-powershell).