# Cannot use cd on Windows Powershell. Path not found

Tags: windows, powershell

## Cannot use cd: file not found

When I run

```
cd C:\Users\zoua2\Downloads\pwa-ecommerce-demo-payment-request-api.zip\pwa-ecommerce-demo-payment-request-api
```

on powershell. It outputs

```
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\zoua2\Downloads\pwa-ecommerce-demo-payment-request-api.zip\pwa-ecommerce-demo-payment-request-api' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd C:\Users\zoua2\Downloads\pwa-ecommerce-demo-payment-request-api.zi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\zoua2\...ent-request-api:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

### Device data:

```
Operating system: Windows 10 64 bit
PSVersionTable Data:
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752                                                                                                                             
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                   
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                   
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752                                                                                                                            
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                           
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                       
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

[image: Administrator:Windows PowerShell ISE]
[image: File Explorer path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because `C:\Users\zoua2\Downloads\pwa-ecommerce-demo-payment-request-api.zip\pwa-ecommerce-demo-payment-request-api` **is not a valid file path**.

Windows programmatically unpacks the archive metadata and allows you to seemlessly "browse" the contents in Explorer, but the entries in the archive don't actually exists as files in the underlying file system - not until you unpack the zip file.

If you don't want to unpack the entire archive to disk, do like Explorer does and [inspect the archive programmatically before extract anything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60872101/712649)!

Comment: I extracted the file into a file folder.

Comment: You may have done so, but not in the screenshot you shared however. Notice in the Windows bar, it has an option for 'extract all'. That's only shown when you're in a zip file.

Comment: @FoxDeploy I think he means he solved his own problem by simply extracting the file